# why sp_who2 shows the query status as sleeping ,eventhough it has been running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

There is a delete query that has been running for an hour.

Just fired `sp_who2` and it shows the status of the query as sleeping, even though it is running. **Why `sp_who2` shows the query status as sleeping**?

Comment: Could you describe the problem three times identically? Seriously, why have you written the question like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process is considered sleeping occasionally when its waits for some resources or being blocked by some other process.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Please suggest me, what could be the issue, 
Have a look on attached link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156721/pyodbc-connection-going-to-sleep-mode

Answer (score 3):

you can try with:

```
dbcc inputbuffer(@Spid)
```

take the SPID with the sp_who2 and see exactly what the is running for that user.